# Typescript: generic that extends a type with a generic (higher kinded types)

Tags: typescript

Say I have an interface

```
interface Applicative<T> {}
```

Now I want to define a function `f` that:

- takes a function and takes a type U extending an Applicative wrapping Any
- and returns an U wrapping a function

How do I define this in Typescript ?

```
 function f<U extends Applicative>(fn: Function, a: U<any>): U<Function>
```

is my naive attempt but this is not valid

Comment: U is also generic. I'm afraid you can not declare generic inside generic argument declaration. May be this helps:
"function f<U extends Applicative<any|Function>>(fn: Function, a: U): U".
Disclaimer: I do understand this is not exactly you wanted.

Comment: @TSV thanks. This compiles but since `any|Function` is as good as `any`, this definition does not guarantee that `f` returns an U wrapping a Function (and nothing else)

Comment: Another my thought was  "function f<U extends Applicative<any>>(fn: Function, a: U): Applicative<Function>" - but this does not give desired function result type...

Comment: @TSV; thanks again but this time there is not guarantee that the type returned by the function is of type U (or derived from U) - and that is one of my requirements

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately,  typescript does not (yet?) implement higher kinded types.

See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213 for details

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you are looking for but it is as close as I think you can get:

```
interface Applicative<T> {}

function f<U>(fn: Function, a: U & Applicative<any>): U & Applicative<Function> {

    return null;
}
```

`a` will have to be both `U` (whatever `U` is) and `Applicative<any>`. `U` can not be defined to be a generic type explicitly I am afraid.

Better typing can be achieved by:

```
function f<U, V>(fn: Function, a: U & Applicative<V>): U & Applicative<Function> { }
```

I am not entirely sure that the return type in my example is exactly what you want. But you should be able to achieve your required result by adding/changing the required interface on the return type e.g.:

```
function f<U, V>(fn: Function, a: U & A<V>): U & A<Function>
function f<U, V>(fn: Function, a: U & A<V>): U & A<Function> & B<V>
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable workaround. Let me test this out and come back to you

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
interface Applicative<T> {}
function f<T, U extends Applicative<T>>(fn: Function, a: U)
```

All you need to do is just provide all arguments needed for `Applicative` (`T`  in this case) to `f` itself, and mark `U` as the one that extends it.

At least that worked for me, hope it will cover your case as well.