# Unwrap/Preserve Generic Constraints of Function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, static, inference

Let's say I have the following generic function.

```
declare function greet<
  Name extends "Alice" | "Bob",
  Rest extends (Name extends "Alice" ? [isMother: boolean] : [isFather: boolean])
>(
  name: Name,
  ...rest: Rest
): void;
```

The second parameter of this function (or at least its label) changes depending on the supplied `name`. I'd like to map the parameters of this function while preserving the generic behavior.

For instance, I'd like to use a HOF to produce a new function––identical to `greet`––except that the parameter types are wrapped with `SomeWrapper`.

```
declare function mapParams<
  I extends (...args: any[]) => any,
  P extends Parameters<I>
>(fn: I): (...args: {[K in keyof P]: SomeWrapper<P[K]>}) => ReturnType<I>;
```

... which would be used as follows:

```
const greet = mapParams(greet);

greet(new SomeWrapper("Alice"), true);
```

Meanwhile, I'd like to preserve the generic behavior. Is this possible?

Comment: You haven't shown `memo`, so it's not clear what you're asking. If `memo` [is an identity function](https://tsplay.dev/mxDpzm), then I'm not sure what issue you're encountering. (Also, I'd use an [overloaded function](https://tsplay.dev/wQ8BjW) for that signature.)

Comment: Just updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: No, TS [doesn't yet have higher-kinded-types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+higher+kinded+types+sort%3Areactions-%2B1-desc).

Comment: Gotcha –– will you please add that as a response & I'll give it the green check?

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but it's more appropriate to mark this question as a duplicate of something like: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33994559/438273